# STM32CubeIDE issues with CMSIS-DSP library files

Tags: stm32, embedded, stm32cubemx, cmsis

I have been trying to add the Library file **libarm_cortexM4lf_math.a** in the Eclipse based STM32CubeIDE as shown in the pictures below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

But the linker is not able to find the library, and drops the following error.

`cannot find -llibarm_cortexM4lf_math`

The complete error log is as follows

```
make -j12 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "CMSIS_DSP_PID_Test1.elf" @"objects.list"  -llibarm_cortexM4lf_math -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"/home/sandhan/Projects/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.3.0/[Nucleo-64 STM32G474RE] Projects/CMSIS_DSP_PID_Test1/STM32G474RETX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="CMSIS_DSP_PID_Test1.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static -L"/home/sandhan/STM32Cube/Repository/Packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.5.1/CMSIS/DSP/Lib/GCC" -D ARM_MATH_CM4 -D __FPU_PRESENT=1 --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.3.0/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.7-2018-q2-update.linux64_1.0.0.201904181610/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -llibarm_cortexM4lf_math
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:44: CMSIS_DSP_PID_Test1.elf] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: When adding the library, use only `arm_cortex_M4lf_math` rather than `libarm_cortex_M4lf_math`. It should work. I believe the GNU toolchain automatically adds the `lib` prefix.

Comment: @swineone Thanks. I didn't know that. I removed the lib prefix, and its working now.